# My android app does not support 4" 4.5" inch screens android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, grid-layout, screen-resolution

I am new in android studio. Recently I created android app using android studio app works fine in Nexus S and Nexus one emulator but in real device their was gridlayout problem.

My Activity_main

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.android.example.braintrainer.MainActivity"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
   android:onClick="start">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go!"
    android:id="@+id/startButton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#ff0eff31"
    android:onClick="start"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#ff0eff31" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/gameRelativeLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30s"
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="#fffffb2e"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#ffff8807"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="31 + 12"
        android:id="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ff141414" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        tools:targetApi="ice_cream_sandwich">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:tag="0"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:background="#ff444eff"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:tag="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:background="#ff11ff46"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:tag="2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:background="#ffff09e4"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:tag="3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:textSize="80sp"
            android:background="#ff0bfffd"
            android:onClick="chooseAnswer" />
    </GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/playAgainButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/gridLayout"
    android:id="@+id/visible"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play Again"
        android:id="@+id/playAgainButton"
        android:onClick="playAgain"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="#dc8919c1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
[image]

[**SCREENSHOT OF PROBLEM**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3xBS.png)

Comment: What is the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: why you are using so many relative layouts, If we have LinearLayout as a best option.

Comment: I have given the screenshot of problem

Comment: You can easily create this type of layout using `LinearLayout` instead of `GridLayout`..!!

Comment: but i don't know how to create this type of layout using LinearLayout

Comment: Thanks Its working for me @Janki gadhiya

Comment: Great.. Happy coding..!!

Answer (score 0):

A set of six generalized densities:-

ldpi (low) ~120dpi mdpi (medium) ~160dpi hdpi (high) ~240dpi xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Screen Size:-

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Provide different layouts for different screen sizes:-

The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in layout-xlarge/

For further reference use this link:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: ok then use this <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Comment: Sorry but this code is also not working ,Can you please suggest another one?? Thanks